# Multiline Raw string confuses Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is part of an UWP project for a multiple save/open dialog with GoogleDrive/OneDrive/DropBox features I'm creating based on my [GOD](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1168518/The-GOD-Google-Onedrive-and-Dropbox-access-in-one) library.

Try putting this to a cpp file:

```
std::wstring OpenFileX = LR"(<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="run" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="runProgress" IsActive="true" Margin="10" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="runBar" Value="0" Maximum="100" Margin="10"/>
            <Button x:Name="runCancel" Margin="10">Cancel</Button>
        </StackPanel>

<Pivot x:Name="pi">
    <PivotItem Header="Local">


        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="30">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="localFile"
                     PlaceholderText="Filename"
                     Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Button x:Name="localPick" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50">...</Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button x:Name="localSave" Margin="0,20,0,0">Open</Button>
        </StackPanel>



    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Google Drive" x:Name="name_google">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="30">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="googleProgress" IsActive="true" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="sp1">
            <TextBox x:Name="googleFile"
                     PlaceholderText="Filename"
                     Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Button x:Name="googleSave" Margin="10,0,0,0" >Open</Button>
                <Button x:Name="googleTop" Margin="10,0,0,0" >Top</Button>
            </StackPanel>

          <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ColDef1" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="RowDef1" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" CanDragItems="True" x:Name="googleList" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
          </Grid>


        </StackPanel>

    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="OneDrive" x:Name="name_one">


        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="30">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="oneProgress" IsActive="true" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="sp2">
            <TextBox x:Name="oneFile"
                     PlaceholderText="Filename"
                     Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Button x:Name="oneSave" Margin="10,0,0,0" >Open</Button>
                <Button x:Name="oneTop" Margin="10,0,0,0" >Top</Button>
            </StackPanel>

          <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ColDef2" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="RowDef2" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" CanDragItems="True" x:Name="oneList" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
          </Grid>


        </StackPanel>


    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="DropBox" x:Name="name_db">
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
        </StackPanel>
)";
```

Then Vs is totally confused on the lines. Pressing F10 to start with WinMain shows code about 10 lines before WinMain.

Is this a known Visual Studio bug? Tried with VS 2019.

Comment: *Then Vs is totally confused on the lines.* What do you mean by that?  Are you getting an error?  Are you not getting the expected results?  Using [this mcve](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44a0621412e72bf2) I don't have any issues with VS 2019.

Comment: It shows current execution e.g. in like 10 where the actual line is 20. Compiler messages wrong as well, e.g. warning on line 15 where it's line 25.

Comment: Weird.  I put a non compiling line of code after the string and the compiler complained about the correct line.  What version of 2019 are you using?  I have 16.0.2

Comment: It seems to me that it's the UWP headers that cause an issue, let me try them.